# Excel - Need to match names with Data multiple times

Tags: excel, vba, indexing, match, vlookup

I need help with the following:

```
Names: Misc: D1: D2: D3:

Name1 stuff2 D  D  M
Name2 car    D  D  M
Name3 black  M  M  SS
Name4 34     SS SS SS
Name5 7      SS SS D
```

I am looking to grab the names for each Day and list them either in a cell. 
So if I am looking for names that have M and SS the following names would be listed into the cell; Name3, Name4, Name5.

Comment: Please show us your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data is in range `A:E` then in `Cell F2` enter the following formula

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$6,SMALL(IF(({"M","SS"}=$C$1:$C$6)+({"M","SS"}=$D$1:$D$6)+({"M","SS"}=$D$1:$D$6)>0,ROW($A$1:$A$6)),ROW(1:1)),1),"")
```

This is an array formula so commit it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. Drag/Copy down as required. Change ranges in formula as per your data.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!